# How can I extract a hexadecimal value from a range of CSS declarations with REGEX php

Tags: php, css, regex

So I am trying to echo some hex values from a CSS file with php, but I only want the hex for each of the CSS declarations. **I only want to return the ones that are within the declarations containing the .u-fill- not .red**

Example CSS:

```
.red {
    background-color: #ff0000 !important; }

.u-fill-grey-darker {
    background-color: #222 !important; }

.u-fill-grey-dark {
    background-color: #444 !important; }

.u-fill-grey-light {
    background-color: #999 !important; }
```

I'd like this php to give me a list of hexs from the CSS file like so:

```
#222
#444
#999
```

So far I can match all the values using regex like so:

```
[#\s\d]
```

But I'd like to do this in a php foreach loop. Is this even possible?!

My php so far looks like this:

```
<?php
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../build/css/styles.css');
$css_contents = file_get_contents($path, true);
$lines = explode("\n", $css_contents);
?>
<div>
<?php foreach($lines as $line) :?>
    <?php if($string = substr(trim($line), 0, 7) == '.u-fill') : ?>
        <?php echo $string; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Expected output

```
<div>#222</div>
<div>#444</div>
<div>#999</div>
```

This however doesnt work and I dont know where to put the regex and which regex to use. Any help will be muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily use a regex for that :

```
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../build/css/styles.css');
$css_contents = file_get_contents($path, true);

$matches;
preg_match_all('/\.u-fill-.*\n.*(#[0-9a-fA-F]+)/', $css_contents, $matches);

foreach($matches as $match) {
    echo '<div>' . $match . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I have tried it but am getting an error:

`: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: Hi Max, I haven't had chance to do that yet. Once I do I'll let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your class is anything that starts with `.u-fill-`

```
/.u-fill-/
```

escape the literal period `\.`

```
/\.u-fill-/
```

ends with one or more characters `.+`

```
/\.u-fill-.+/
```

non-capturing group including newlines `(?s:)`

```
/(?s:\.u-fill-.+)/
```

but don't be greedy `+?`

```
/(?s:\.u-fill-.+?)/
```

Now for the actual value, we'll need a capturing group `()`

```
/(?s:\.u-fill-.+?)()/
```

we know it will begin with a hash `#` numbers `\d` at least one or more `+`

```
/(?s:\.u-fill-.+?)(#\d+)/
```

This is enough to satisfy your given example. But we can do better knowing that CSS can have letters `[A-F]` besides just numbers.

```
/(?s:\.u-fill-.+?)(#[\dA-F]+)/
```

And let's make sure that's a case-insensitive comparison `(?i:)`

```
/(?s:\.u-fill-.+?)(?i:(#[\dA-F]+))/
```

So finally we're left with:

```
$css_contents = file_get_contents($path, true);

preg_match_all('/(?s:\.u-fill-.+?)(?i:(#[\dA-F]+))/', $css_contents, $matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
    echo "<div>$match</div>\n";
}
```

```html
<div>#222</div>
<div>#444</div>
<div>#999</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that reply Jeff, you have really explained what I need to do. I will certainly give this a try.